# Is it possible to specify in Dockerfile to use official image as base?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build docker images and put them in a repo. However, I want my Ubuntu image to just be called `ubuntu`. This results in `docker build` using my image as a base for new image. I know the easiest solution is to just name image differently, but I've been wondering, is it possible to have `FROM` look only in docker hub for the base image?

Comment: Yes you can do that. While pushing the image just use your repo username. Like 
`docker push username/react-redux-api-example:tagname`
then use your base image as
`FROM username/react-redux-api-example:tagname`

Comment: I know that's how it works when pushing to repo, but for tinkering purposes I didn't add repo name to tag.

Comment: How will it refer to your image? if you dont add you repo name in the beginning? Otherwise it will pull official images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give your custom images names that conflict with standard Docker Hub images.  You can `docker rmi` your misnamed local image, and the next time you need it Docker will pull it from Docker Hub for you.

Docker generally has the assumption that, if it already has an image named `ubuntu` or whatever else, then the local copy is the one it's looking for and it doesn't need to contact Docker Hub at all.  There isn't a provision to have multiple images with the same name; you can't have "my own personal private `ubuntu`" and "`ubuntu` from Docker Hub" as separate images with the same name.

The easiest and most unambiguous way around this is to give your custom base image some other name; if you call your customized base image `myname/base` instead of `ubuntu` then there won't be this conflict any more.